# Is apache ignite call back function blocking or non blocking?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, callback, ignite

I am using apache ignite,
there is a code block that looks like this:

```java
query.setLocalListener(cacheEntryEvents -> {
   Set<String> taskIds = new HashSet<>();
   for (CacheEntryEvent<? extends String, ? extends String> e: cacheEntryEvents){
       if (e.getEventType().equals(EventType.CREATED)) {
           taskIds.add(e.getKey());
       }
   }

   if (!taskIds.isEmpty()){
       Set<String> processedTaskId = this.process(taskIds);
       taskProcessed.addAndGet(processedTaskId.size());
       removeCacheEntryExecutor.removeCache(processedTaskId, inactiveTaskCache);
       log.info("Finish processing {} distributed inactive task", processedTaskId.size());
       log.info("---------------------------Current total processed task: " + taskProcessed);
   }
});
```

My question is that, does the callback function in this local listener executed as a non-blocking function in a separate thread? Or does it blocks the listener? If the latter case is true, then what happens when `this.process(taskIds)` takes too long to execute? If the former case is true, how does it manage the separated thread?

Answer (score 0):

No, Continuous Query should not block the caller and the callback function is being executed on a dedicated thread. Check a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68828208/ignite-server-hang-there-when-listen-to-remote-event-evt-node-left/68863066#68863066)

To answer the second question, you need to share your `this.process(taskIds)` method first.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So if a blocking function is invoked in the listener's callback function, then will it execute normally? I tried to remove cache entry in the same thread with the callback function, but it does not work. I have to use an executor to schedule that cache removal in a separate thread.

Comment: Yes, it will be executed normally using blocking functions. As per the second option... Can you please share a reproducer or a CQ listener with the removal ops? I'm almost sure it should work that way, i.e. you should be able to remove a key inside a listener, but I might be missing something.